# Sql Exception : "Error converting data type bigint to nvarchar." , when returning a value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a simple application that save user details and generates an ID and based on that ID, their Education details are saved to table.

This is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAVE_USER_DETAILS 
    @tablePersonalDetails Resume_Personal_Details READONLY, 
    @tableEducation Resume_Education READONLY, 
    @returnValue BIGINT OUTPUT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    DECLARE @HeaderID BIGINT; 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION Tran_Resume 

        INSERT INTO YCTC_CV_USER_PERSONAL_DETAIL (CV_USER_NAME, CV_USER_FATHER_NAME, CV_USER_DOB, 
                                                  CV_USER_MARITAL_STATUS, 
                                                  CV_USER_PERMANENT_ADDRESS, CV_USER_PRESENT_ADDRESS, 
                                                  CV_USER_CONTACT, CV_USER_EMAIL, CV_USER_GENDER) 
           SELECT  
               user_name, father_name, user_dob,
               marital_status,
               permanent_address, present_address, 
               user_contact, user_email, user_gender 
           FROM  
               @tablePersonalDetails 

        SET @HeaderID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()); 

        INSERT INTO YCTC_CV_USER_EDUCATION (CV_USER_ID, QUALIFICATION, INSTITUTION, BOARD_UNIVERSITY, PYEAR,RESULT)
            SELECT 
                @HeaderID, qualification, institution, board_university, pyear, result 
            FROM 
                @tableEducation;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION Tran_Resume 

    SET @returnValue = @HeaderID

    SELECT @returnValue; 
    RETURN(0) ; 
END
```

Below is the user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE Resume_Personal_Details AS TABLE
(
    [user_name] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [father_name] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [user_dob] [DATE] NOT NULL,
    [marital_status] [TINYINT] NULL,
    [permanent_address] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [present_address] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [user_contact] [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
    [user_email] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [user_gender] [TINYINT] NULL,
    [Job_obj] [VARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TYPE Resume_Education AS TABLE
(
    [qualification] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [institution] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [board_university] [VARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [pyear] [VARCHAR](4) NOT NULL,
    [result] [VARCHAR](10) NOT NULL
)
```

And below is the C# code (sending all rows to their user-defined table and sending the ID to the C# code)

```
ReturnMessage _returnMessage = new ReturnMessage(); 
// Above class has 2 variables : bool ReturnStatus; string Message ;

try 
{
    string DateOfBirth = data.UserDOB.ToString().Replace("/", "-");    
           //.Substring(6, 4) + "-" + data.UserDOB.ToString().Substring(3, 2) + "-" + data.UserDOB.ToString().Substring(0, 2);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Add columns  
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user_name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("father_name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user_dob", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("marital_status", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("permanent_address", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("present_address", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user_contact", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user_email", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("user_gender", typeof(int)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Job_obj", typeof(string)));

    // Add rows  
    dt.Rows.Add(data.UserName, data.FatherName, DateOfBirth, data.MaritalStatus,
                data.UserPermanentAddress, data.UserPresentAddress,
                data.Contact, data.UserEmail, data.Gender, data.User_Job_Objective);

    DataTable EducationDataTable = new DataTable();
    EducationDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("qualification", typeof(string)));
    EducationDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("institution", typeof(string)));
    EducationDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("board_university", typeof(string)));
    EducationDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pyear", typeof(string)));
    EducationDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("result", typeof(string)));

    foreach(EducationDetails _educationalDetails in data.EducationDetails) 
    {
        EducationDataTable.Rows.Add(_educationalDetails.Qualification,
                                    _educationalDetails.Institution,
                                    _educationalDetails.University,
                                    _educationalDetails.Year,
                                    _educationalDetails.Result);
    }

    long ReturnValue = 0;

    DBHelper.Parameters[] colParameters = new DBHelper.Parameters[3] {
              new DBHelper.Parameters("@tablePersonalDetails", dt),
              new DBHelper.Parameters("@tableEducation", EducationDataTable),
              new DBHelper.Parameters("@returnValue", "", ParameterDirection.Output),
    };

    int RetCount = objHelper.gExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SAVE_USER_DETAILS", colParameters);
    intHeaderID = Convert.ToInt64(objHelper.oCommand.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value);

    _returnMessage.Message = Convert.ToString(intHeaderID);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    _returnMessage.Message = "Fail";
}
```

When `ExecuteNonQuery()` is called, it generated an exception but the all the data is Inserted successfully.

> Error converting data type bigint to nvarchar

From all my testing, I am sure the problem lies in Stored procedure, but what, that's what I am not getting.

If any other information is required, do notify, I will provide.

Comment: You can add try catch inside your stored procedure, then execute it through SQL Server Management studio via debug and see if it generates an exception message.

Comment: Have you tried to cast `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to `BigInt` before setting it to `@HeaderID`?

Comment: Don't know which DBHelper you are using, but most probably `new DBHelper.Parameters("@returnValue", "", ParameterDirection.Output)` creates a parameter of type string/nvarchar. Try create `long` parameter

Comment: @Ronaldo Yes, I have Tried to cast Scope_IDENTITY() to BigInt , it was of no help.

Comment: @Serg , DBHeliper is just a helper class which I created to deal with the sql connection, executing commands etc pupose. Below is the defination of Parameter method :                                                                                                              `public Parameters(string Name, object Value, ParameterDirection Direction)            {
string strParamName = Name;
object oParamValue = Value;
ParameterDirection pParamDirection = Direction;
int IntSize = 0;
string strColumnName = "";
DType = DbType.String; // just an enum
 } `

Comment: Check the definition of the CV_USER_ID column in the YCTC_CV_USER_EDUCATION table.  That's the only thing you are trying to put a bigint into (aside from @returnValue which is declared a bigint).

Comment: Check parameter size. You can get "Error converting data type bigint to nvarchar." when trying to return value longer then the size of nvarchar can accept

Answer (score 0):

If data are successfully inserted then error occurs when returning parameter from the proc.
Check output parameter size. Quick demo

```
create proc test (@retval bigint out)
as
    set @retval = 123;
go

declare @res nvarchar(2);
exec test @res out;
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 2, Procedure test, Line 4 Error converting
>   data type bigint to nvarchar.

Comment: Here your out parameter is bigint and your are passing nvarchar(2) , obviously it will give an error, but in my case the out parameter is of type Bigint and the value being store in it is also bigint. `SET @HeaderID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()); -- @HeaderID is of type Bigint ; SET @returnValue = @HeaderID; SELECT @returnValue ` So as every type is bigint, from where this nvarchar is coming ?

Comment: You created output parameter in c# code of type `DbType.String`. My demo does the same just in pure T-sql. Note in the `test` proc there is no any `nvarchar` data, same as your proc. Check the size of output paremeter in c#.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, it solved the error. I should have sent int value instead of string, which actually caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the Parameter which I was sending to the proc ,
earlier I was doing

```cs
DBHelper.Parameters[] colParameters = new DBHelper.Parameters[1] {
                new DBHelper.Parameters("@returnValue","",ParameterDirection.Output),
            };
objHelper.gExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SAVE_USER_DETAILS", colParameters);
```

The Parameters method takes `string Name, object Value, ParameterDirection Direction` , so when gExecuteNonQuery() hits, the expected Value was int(i.e 0), instead I was sending string(" "), which created an exception

```
'Error converting data type bigint to nvarchar '
```

so When I did the below code

```
DBHelper.Parameters[] colParameters = new DBHelper.Parameters[1] {
                new DBHelper.Parameters("@returnValue",0,ParameterDirection.Output),
            };
objHelper.gExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SAVE_USER_DETAILS", colParameters);
```

Solved the Error.